# Cannot create setuptools rpm: error: Two files on one line

Tags: python, rpm, setuptools, setup.py, rpmbuild

I am trying to build an rpm from setuptools 7.0 source https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools.

The steps that I do are:

- download sources and unpack them
- in setuptools dir I run `python setup.py bdist_rpm`

I use Python 2.7.8 and Red Hat 6.2 (64 bit)

Log:

```
running bdist_rpm
running egg_info
writing requirements to setuptools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing setuptools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to setuptools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to setuptools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to setuptools.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'setuptools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'setuptools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/setuptools.spec'
running sdist
running check
creating setuptools-7.0
creating setuptools-7.0/_markerlib
creating setuptools-7.0/docs
creating setuptools-7.0/docs/_templates
creating setuptools-7.0/docs/_theme
creating setuptools-7.0/docs/_theme/nature
creating setuptools-7.0/docs/_theme/nature/static
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools.egg-info
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools/command
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools/tests
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools/tests/indexes
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority/simple
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority/simple/foobar
creating setuptools-7.0/setuptools/tests/svn_data
creating setuptools-7.0/tests
creating setuptools-7.0/tests/shlib_test
making hard links in setuptools-7.0...
hard linking .gitignore -> setuptools-7.0
hard linking .hgignore -> setuptools-7.0
.........
.........
hard linking tests/shlib_test/setup.py -> setuptools-7.0/tests/shlib_test
hard linking tests/shlib_test/test_hello.py -> setuptools-7.0/tests/shlib_test
copying setup.cfg -> setuptools-7.0
Writing setuptools-7.0/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'setuptools-7.0' (and everything under it)
copying dist/setuptools-7.0.tar.gz -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SOURCES
building RPMs
rpmbuild -ba --define _topdir /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm --clean build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/setuptools.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VPynSG
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD
+ cd /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD
+ rm -rf setuptools-7.0
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SOURCES/setuptools-7.0.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xvvf -
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-11-03 17:55 setuptools-7.0/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2014-11-03 17:55 setuptools-7.0/setuptools/
-rw-rw-rw- root/root       714 2014-10-19 15:11 setuptools-7.0/setuptools/windows_support.py
-rw-rw-rw- root/root      5195 2014-09-30 04:49 setuptools-7.0/setuptools/__init__.py
-rwxrwxrwx root/root     74752 2014-09-30 04:37 setuptools-7.0/setuptools/cli-64.exe
......
......
-rw-rw-rw- root/root      4813 2014-11-03 17:55 setuptools-7.0/setuptools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
-rw-rw-rw- root/root      8772 2014-10-19 14:00 setuptools-7.0/README.txt
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd setuptools-7.0
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.169Vak
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD
+ cd setuptools-7.0
+ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
copying pkg_resources.py -> build/lib
......
......
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.h1D3YX
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD
+ cd setuptools-7.0
+ python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed -O1 --root=/root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/setuptools-7.0-1.x86_64 --record=INSTALLED_FILES
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
writing byte-compilation script '/tmp/tmp56GdDT.py'
/usr/local/bin/python -O /tmp/tmp56GdDT.py
removing /tmp/tmp56GdDT.py
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
writing requirements to setuptools.egg-info/requires.txt
writing setuptools.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to setuptools.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to setuptools.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to setuptools.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'setuptools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'setuptools.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
removing '/root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/setuptools-7.0-1.x86_64/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-7.0-py2.7.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying setuptools.egg-info to /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/setuptools-7.0-1.x86_64/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-7.0-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
Installing easy_install script to /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/setuptools-7.0-1.x86_64/usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.7 script to /root/xxx/robot_tests/test_env_scripts/test1/setuptools-7.0/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILDROOT/setuptools-7.0-1.x86_64/usr/local/bin
writing list of installed files to 'INSTALLED_FILES'
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-static-archive
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-comment-note
Processing files: setuptools-7.0-1.noarch
error: Two files on one line: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script
error: File must begin with "/": (dev).tmpl


RPM build errors:
    Two files on one line: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/script
    File must begin with "/": (dev).tmpl
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

attached `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/setuptools.spec`

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8815648/

and `INSTALLED_FILES`

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8819582/

Comment: Can you include the contents of the `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/SPECS/setuptools.spec` file and the `INSTALLED_FILES` file?

Comment: @EtanReisner Please take a look http://paste.ubuntu.com/8815648/

Comment: That's the spec file. What about `INSTALLED_FILES`? Also... for the love of god and all that is holy that is a **horrible** `%description` block. It made me want to claw my eyes out. Whoever decided that was a good idea needs to be shot.

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry haven't seen that http://paste.ubuntu.com/8819582/

Comment: Line 68 in that paste is the problem. (And is roughly what I expected.) There is a file with a space in the name. That space is not escaped or quoted (I'm not even sure I know how to do that properly in a spec file) and that is causing the parsing of the `INSTALLED_FILES` file by rpm to fail. That file will need to be renamed or removed or that space will need to be escaped somehow. If that isn't a file you added I would file an issue with setuptools about it.

Comment: @EtanReisner That was it:) Although I still have an issue with built rpm requiring `/usr/local/bin/python` and I do have my Python installed there but I do not know how to remove that dependency. (You can post that comment as answer)

Comment: That's probably coming from the shebang line of one of the packages python scripts. Depending on which script you may be able to prevent it from saying that (by controlling how you configure setuptools during the build) or you may need to disable automatic dependencies (which is an all-or-nothing proposition in many versions of rpm/etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 68 of `INSTALLED_FILES` (in that second paste) is the problem. (And is roughly what I expected.)

There is a file with a space in the name.

That space is not escaped or quoted (I'm not even sure I know how to do that properly in file list file used in a spec file `%files -f <file>`) and that is causing the parsing of the `INSTALLED_FILES` file by rpm to fail.

That file will need to be renamed or removed or that space will need to be escaped somehow.

If that isn't a file you added I would file an issue with setuptools about it since they should be handling (or avoiding) this correctly.